# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>'. while finding data from mongo in flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter

```
void updateCoinsDB() async {
    var db = await mongoDB.Db.create(MONGO_URL);
    await db.open();

    final collection = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME);
    var user = collection
        .find(mongoDB.where.match("email", "demoname@gmail.com").excludeFields([
          "_id",
          "email",
          "UID",
          "UserName",
        ]))
        .toList();
    var Coins = user['earnedCoinsT'];<< getting error over here
    print(Coins);

    await db.close();
}
```

i got this perticular line from stackoverflow itself but it is showing this type of error (Compile time)

i also tried to do it this way

```
(doc.data() as dynamic)['earnedCoinsT'],
```

but that shows runtime error

Comment: which libraries you use to work with Mongo on Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

`collection.find` has a type of Future. Try to use `await` keyword before `collection.find` to make this future executed and receive a type of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Also, as far as I see from your code, you're trying to find a particular user (with a particular email) to get `earnedCoinsT` from this object. So you're searching a single entity (`Map<String, dynamic>`), not a list of entities (`List<Map<String, dynamic>>`). In case you're using mongo_dart library, replace `collection.find` with `collection.findOne`

The full code is:

```
    var user = collection
      .find(mongoDB.where.match("email", "demoname@gmail.com").excludeFields([
        "_id",
        "email",
        "UID",
        "UserName",
      ])); << Remove toList here because it isn't a list now
```